# not able to hide message box in wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython, subprocess, wxwidgets

hi guys tried everything and now i am asking your suggestions.

I am not able to hide my messagebox.

code is:

```
    ans = wx.MessageBox("length = %s , height = %s " % (str(len), str(ht)))

    if ans = wx.Yes:

        subprocess.call("pword | sudo -S ./Install.sh %s %s" % (str(len),str(ht)))
```

3rd line take around 6-7 min to complete .till that time message box will be on screen ,i want to make it hide till installation process get finish.
I tried hide ,future call,close ,Disable..but everytime i get 'int object has no attribute "  ".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message box must be hidden and destroyed by the time `wxMessageBox()` returns, there must be something else going on here.

In general, if you want to be sure that all pending events have been processed (and so all windows that should be repainted/resized/closed were indeed handled), use `wx.CallAfter()` to launch your long-running process at a slightly later time.

Of course, running a blocking operation taking several minutes from a GUI program is a bad idea anyhow, but this is another story...

Answer (score 0):

If you need more control over the message box use a message dialog instead.  The message box returns the answer directly, so you can't control the window.  Creating a message dialog lets you control the window.

Here is a simple example:

```
import wx

app = wx.App(False)
box = wx.MessageDialog(None, 'Yes or No?', caption='Dialog Title', style=wx.YES_NO | wx.YES_DEFAULT)
result = box.ShowModal()
box.Destroy()
if result == wx.ID_YES:
    print 'yes'
else:
    print 'no'
```

Comment: but now i am having trouble to show destroyed panel when i press "no"

Comment: The code in this answer does exactly the same thing as `wxMessageBox()` function does internally and so can't possibly change anything.